# How detect tap on row of custom table view in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have used a prototype cell in iOS & I have added a image & label on the cell. This is how I am able to display the image & text on the cell. But due to this I am unable to select the whole row & delegate method for didrowselect is not working. Please tell the solution?

**Code of table view delegates**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"delegate called");

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"row in section called");
    return[arr_userAlbums count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tableCell";
    AlbumCell *cell = [self.tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                              forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UserAlbum *user_allbum=[arr_userAlbums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cell_label.text=user_allbum.album_name;
    cell.cell_img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"];
    [cell.cell_img setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_allbum.album_image]]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;



       return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    NSLog(@"row event occured");
}
```

**AlbumCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AlbumCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cell_img;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cell_label;

@end
```

Comment: Hi, please can you paste your code

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath Should  work,Check whether u set your delegate or not.

Comment: I select the delegate

Answer (score 0):

Verify you touched view

```
 -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    NSLog(@"touch at %@", touch.view);
    if ([NSStringFromClass([touch.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellContentView"])
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
}
```